# Smart card reader compatibility issue

Tags: c#, smartcard, smartcard-reader

Read value from Mifare 4K card using Ask reader is perfect.  the same card  reading from Acs reader some time return correct value and some time return 67 00 wrong  length error but am using same command in csharp language.

I am using APDU commands.

Kindly advice to resolve this issue.

Comment: How is a driver or hardware update a programming question? Is that the first time you have crappy drivers or crappy hardwre cause issues? Thsoe are the only 2 resolutions. Either the drivers crap out, or the hardware is crap or defective.

Comment: Yes your are correct I tried with 2 more computers but same issue

Comment: So, then you're at the wrong place, because this is for programming questions.

Comment: Suppose you know advice